# Adding data value per query - Mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I wonder if this is gonna work in plain mysql query.
I have 2 columns qty and bal. In every item from quantity, it must be increase or decrease in balance just like below.

```
--------------------
quantity | balance
--------------------
10.000   | 10.000
1.000    | 11.000
-10.000  | 1.000
```

I tried using += assignment operator but it gives me a syntax error.

```
select
    group_concat(format(item_ledger_entry.Quantity,3)order by Posting_Date separator '\n') AS quantity
    group_concat(0+=format(item_ledger_entry.Quantity,3) order by Posting_Date separator '\n')  as bal,
    from item
    group by item.No_;
```

Is there a way to do this in a simpler way?

Comment: Please add a sample and the expected data.

Comment: @cdaiga 
expected data should look like the first result mentioned above.
Quantity is a normal query while balance will depend on quantity's value. it will add up or decrease, depends on its sign.

Comment: I don't understand your question so well! It's still not clear to me.

Comment: Is seems like you want to calculate a *running total*. You can do this using variables in MySQL. There are plenty of examples here in SO.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Yes that's what I wanna do. Is it doable in a plain mysql query?

Comment: Yes it is. Just google 'MySQL running total'.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
i have used temporary and derived table ,check this
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/93be81/1